# Validating Video Timestamp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I need to do validation of a video timestamp. So basically in my case, the number of hours can be greater than 24. What would be the best way to do this validation in Java? For a standard 24 hour validation, I do the following.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime.parse("20:00:12", dateFormat);
```

I would like to do a similar validation in my front-end Javascript as well.
For normal 24 hour pattern I tested using the Regex: `new RegExp("(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}")`; Is there a Jquery plugin similar to input mask, which I could use to enforce this pattern in the UI text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, why not just use first principles:

```
String timestamp = "343:45:37";
String[] components = timestamp.split(":");
boolean validTimestamp = false;
int h = -1, m = -1, s = -1;
try {
    if (validTimestamp = components[1].length() == 2 && components[2].length() == 2) {
        h = Integer.valueOf(components[0]);
        m = Integer.valueOf(components[1]);
        s = Integer.valueOf(components[2]);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
validTimestamp = validTimestamp && h >= 0 && m >= 0 && m < 60 && s >= 0 && s < 60;
```

Comment: All of the individual elements should also be of 2 digits

Comment: Sorry, but I thought the OP said that more than 24 hours need to be accepted. Besides, there's no need to check the length of the individual components since their numerical values are checked on the last line.

Comment: Yes except for hour everything else has to be of digits..with this logic even: 9:1:1 is valid which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Aparently I cannot add a comment, so I will post it as an answer.

My strategy would be to use the `<input type="time">` tag, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time.

There is also a polyfill for old browser support. https://github.com/jonstipe/time-polyfill

Other than that, I like to rely on the backend to provide most validation and the error responses.

Comment: time attribute does 24 hour validation. Also In my case there is no concept of AM/PM